# Erro ao finalizar Activity através de outra classe

Tags: android, funções, android-activity

Alguém sabe explicar porque ocorre o erro `LISTADO NO FINAL DA PERGUNTA`, encerrando a aplicação, quando eu tento finalizar o aplicativo através de uma outra classe:

**classe1.class**:

```
    ...
    ...
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
    NetworkAvailable internet = new NetworkAvailable();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (!internet.isNetworkAvailable(this)){
    alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Sem internet!", false);

    if (alert.Saindo()){

       //O ERRO ACONTECE PELO FINISH(), EU QUERIA QUE ESSA FUNÇÃO EXECUTASSE
       //DEPOIS QUE EU CANCELASSE LÁ NA classe3.    
       //O app NEM INICIA, se eu deixar esse finish aqui, mas se eu o retirar,
       //O LOG executa:

       Log("Finalizado","Fechando a aplicação!")
            finish();

        }

    }

}




  }
```

**classe2.class**:

```
public class NetworkAvailable{

        public boolean isNetworkAvailable (final Context context) {
            ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();


            boolean isAvailable = false;
            if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()){
                /* LARGURA E AUTURA GERALToast.makeText(this, "LARGURA > " + largura, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
                Toast.makeText(context, "CONECTADO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                isAvailable = true;
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(context, "NÃO CONECTADO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                isAvailable = false;
            }
            return isAvailable;

        }
}
```

**classe3.class**:

```
public class AlertDialogManager {

    public boolean showAlertDialog(final Context context, final String title, final Boolean status) {


    if(status == false){
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
     builder.setCancelable(false);
     builder.setTitle(title);

     builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                       


             Log.v("CANCELANDO", "cancelado");
             showAlertDialog(context, title, true);
             Saindo();

         }
     });

     builder.setPositiveButton("Tentar novamente", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
         {

            final ConnectivityManager conectivtyManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);  
            if (conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null  
                    && conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()  
                    && conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {  


            } 
             dialog.dismiss();
             showAlertDialog(context, title, false);
         }
     });
     AlertDialog dialog = builder.create(); // calling builder.create after adding buttons
     dialog.show();
    return status;
    }
    return status;  
    }

    public boolean Saindo(){

        Log.v("SAINDO", "saiu");        
        return true;

    }



}
```

---

```
01-26 22:17:05.721: E/WindowManager(25592): Activity ffitteste.favoritos.mapa.rafael.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@418654f0 that was originally added here
01-26 22:17:05.721: E/WindowManager(25592): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity ffitteste.favoritos.mapa.rafael.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@418654f0 that was originally added here
01-26 22:17:05.721: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:351)
01-26 22:17:05.721: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:279)
01-26 22:17:05.721: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
01-26 22:17:05.721: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
01-26 22:17:05.721: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
01-26 22:17:05.721: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
01-26 22:17:05.721: E/WindowManager(25592):     at ffitteste.favoritos.mapa.rafael.AlertDialogManager.showAlertDialog(AlertDialogManager.java:48)
01-26 22:17:05.721: E/WindowManager(25592):     at ffitteste.favoritos.mapa.rafael.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:103)
01-26 22:17:05.721: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-26 22:17:05.721: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
01-26 22:17:05.721: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
01-26 22:17:05.721: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
01-26 22:17:05.721: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
01-26 22:17:05.721: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
01-26 22:17:05.721: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-26 22:17:05.721: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-26 22:17:05.721: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
01-26 22:17:05.721: E/WindowManager(25592):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-26 22:17:05.721: E/WindowManager(25592):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-26 22:17:05.721: E/WindowManager(25592):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
01-26 22:17:05.721: E/WindowManager(25592):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
01-26 22:17:05.721: E/WindowManager(25592):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-26 22:17:05.729: E/WindowManager(25592): Activity ffitteste.favoritos.mapa.rafael.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41776208 that was originally added here
01-26 22:17:05.729: E/WindowManager(25592): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity ffitteste.favoritos.mapa.rafael.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41776208 that was originally added here
01-26 22:17:05.729: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:351)
01-26 22:17:05.729: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:279)
01-26 22:17:05.729: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
01-26 22:17:05.729: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
01-26 22:17:05.729: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
01-26 22:17:05.729: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
01-26 22:17:05.729: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:932)
01-26 22:17:05.729: E/WindowManager(25592):     at ffiteteste.favoritos.servicos.rafael.GPSTracker.showSettingsAlert(GPSTracker.java:194)
01-26 22:17:05.729: E/WindowManager(25592):     at ffitteste.favoritos.mapa.rafael.MainActivity.GPSzoom(MainActivity.java:819)
01-26 22:17:05.729: E/WindowManager(25592):     at ffitteste.favoritos.mapa.rafael.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:164)
01-26 22:17:05.729: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-26 22:17:05.729: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
01-26 22:17:05.729: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
01-26 22:17:05.729: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
01-26 22:17:05.729: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
01-26 22:17:05.729: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
01-26 22:17:05.729: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-26 22:17:05.729: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-26 22:17:05.729: E/WindowManager(25592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
01-26 22:17:05.729: E/WindowManager(25592):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-26 22:17:05.729: E/WindowManager(25592):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-26 22:17:05.729: E/WindowManager(25592):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
01-26 22:17:05.729: E/WindowManager(25592):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
01-26 22:17:05.729: E/WindowManager(25592):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Alguém se manifesta por favor  kkkk

Comment: Poderia incluir o **stacktrace** que aparece no logcat?

Comment: Responderam-me isto: Faça sua função retornar um boolean e a própria activity é que se fecha. Na arquitetura do Android vc não deve manter instância de Activity em outra classe ou Activity.

Comment: Está correto, @Wakim?

Comment: Não tem isso de certo ou errado, mas é uma boa prática sim não expor sua `Activity` por questões de acoplamento. Sempre que precisar passar um instância da `Activity` para outra classe, pense no *pattern Observer/Listener*. Mas em termos práticos, esse código funciona*. Funciona se você instânciar o objeto  `NetworkAvailable` antes de usar (hehe).

Comment: Como você está passando inicializando o membro `saindo`  com a instância da outra Activity?

Comment: @AndréRibeiro, tudo que tenho é isto. Tem como fazer isso funcionar?

Comment: Sem o stacktrace e o resto do código fica difícil identificar o problema.

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta.

Answer (score 3):

Amigo, o primeiro problema aqui é: o seu método `Saindo` sempre retorna `true`. Daí, a Activity vai chamar o `finish` imediatamente, e deixará para trás o Dialog (o stack trace está dizendo exatamente isso, que a Activity saiu e deixou uma janela).

Sugiro que você siga [este exemplo](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html). Ele mostra como criar um Dialog e uma Interface, e como fazer a Activity chamar o Dialog e implementar esta interface. Assim, fica estabelecida uma comunicação entre sua Activity e o Dialog.

Se você utilizar o *wizard* de criação de novo Fragment do Andoid Studio (exemplo [aqui](https://www.airpair.com/android/fragments-android-studio#3-generating-fragments-with-android-studio)), ele vai criar este esquema de Interface Callbacks. É ótimo para usar de exemplo (até porque Dialogs estendem Fragments).

Comment: Você está certo quanto a tudo que disse, mas quando eu retorno `false`, no `Saindo`, esse erro também acontece. Como ele finaliza ANTES de eu EXECUTAR a função? Eu quero que ele CANCELE SOMENTE quando eu clicar em CANCELAR do DIALOGO.

Comment: Para fazer o que você quer, você deve estabelecer uma comunicação entre o Dialog e a Activity. Na minha resposta citei exemplos de como fazer isso.

Comment: Então o problema está somente na comunicação? Eu não posso sair criando classe terceiras para manipular atividades com suas funções?

Comment: Sua classe não está manipulando a Activity. Quem está chamando o `finish` é a própria Activity. O que acontece é: se você quer que a Activity termine quando o usuário clique no botão Cancelar, você deve utilizar um método formal de comunicação, para que seu código não vire uma bagunça completa. Código bagunçado dificulta que você mesmo possa entender ele no futuro, e pode esconder falhas de desempenho e segurança.